# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: html, syntax-error, parse-error

I'm having a problem regarding Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING. I tried every solution in available online but still I got the same error over and over again.

So the problem is:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\wamp\www\RedCross\load.php on line 25

load.php

```
<?php

include_once('connect.php');

$EventNum = $_POST['ename'];
//die('You sent: ' . $selStudent);

//Run DB query
$query = "SELECT Price FROM events WHERE EventID = '".$EventNum."' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Fn another_php_file.php ERROR: ' .    mysql_error());
$num_rows_returned = mysql_num_rows($result);
//die('Query returned ' . $num_rows_returned . ' rows.');

//Prepare response html markup
$r = "  
        <div class='control-group'>
            <label class='control-label' for='price'>Price </label>
                <div class='controls'>
";

//Parse mysql results and create response string. Response can be an html table, a full     page, or just a few characters
if ($num_rows_returned > 0) {   
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    

    $r = $r . "<input type='text' name='price' id='price' class='input-xlarge'  value = " . $row['Price'] . " readonly>";

   }
     $r = $r .  "<center>
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-large btn- danger' name='submit' id='submit'>Join!</button>
            </center>";

//The response echoed below will be inserted into the 
echo $r;
} else {
    $r = '<p>sorry there is no available staff for this</p>';
   // $r = $r . '</select><input type="submit" name ="go" value="press me">';
$r = $r . '</div></div>';

//The response echoed below will be inserted into the 
echo $r;
}

//Add this extra button for fun

?>
```

Line 25 is this code:
[image]

Even though I put spaces before it making this line not in line 25 still the error is in line 25.

Please help.

Comment: [Don't use mysql_* extension](http://www.php.net/en/mysql_query) as it is deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: There is no syntax error in the whole code you posted, it parses fine. (_“Even though I put spaces before it making this line not in line 25 still the error is in line 25”_ – that’s even more of an indicator that you’re most likely looking in the wrong place.) Besides that, you should at least learn the basics of the syntax to a level where you can fix simple parse errors yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in line 25 to line below and test:

```
$r = $r . '<input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="input-xlarge"  value = ' . $row["Price"] . ' readonly>';
```